# In Windows 8 Chrome The Search Box Stylings Got Messed Up?

Tags: google-chrome, css, windows-8

I just added some stylings to the search box which make the corners round and add some more effects. When trying the site in Chrome and firefox under Linux, things are working fine. Its also working fine in IE 10 (in windows 8). But in Windows 8 Chrome (Not the Metro version), the stylings got messed up! why is it? Here are the stylings I added :

```
    #top-search {
        border: 1px solid #BABABA;
        -webkit-border-radius: 18px 18px 18px 18px;
        -moz-border-radius: 18px 18px 18px 18px;
        -o-border-radius: 18px 18px 18px 18px;
        border-radius: 18px 18px 18px 18px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px #CFCFCF;
        color: #696969;
        float: right;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin-right: 2%;
        margin-top: 8px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        padding: 3px 3px 3px 7px;
        width: 6%;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
        &:hover, &:focus, {
            opacity: 1;
            width: 8%;
        }
    }
```

Here's how the search box appear :

[image: Searchbox screnshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply changed the input type from "search" to "text"